# How to split the long task that straddles `_app.tsx` and `pages/index.tsx` in Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I use NextJS and try to improve the performance along the CoreWebVitals.
I would like to split the long task that straddles `_app.tsx` and `pages/index.tsx`.

[image]

In the image above, the tree on the left is for `_app.tsx` and the tree on the right is for `pages/index.tsx`.
I can simply run it asynchronously, but I don't know how to do it with NextJS.

Is there any good way?